# How to present viewController while I can still see the background viewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertcontroller

For example, when I present UIActivityViewController or UIAlertController, I can still see the background viewController, and I do not want to embed viewControllerB in viewContollerA.

Comment: Are you talking about having something like a popover view (view that isn't full screen and shows up over the existing view controller), or are you talking about the animation of how the UIAlertController comes up?

Comment: follow this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33382629/how-to-make-popup-menu-in-ios-universal-app/33382761#33382761

Comment: Yes, I am asking about the animation of how the UIAlertController comes up, and when I want to show UIAlertController, I just need to present, how to encapsulate

Answer (score 1):

`[self presentViewController:viewControllerHere animated:YES completion:nil];`

Answer (score 0):

You Can implement like this for UIAlertController

```
    UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Title" message:@"Message" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    UIAlertAction *cancelAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel " style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
        NSLog(@"cancel");
    }];
    [alertController addAction:cancelAction];
    [self presentViewController: alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
```